# Request failed, xhr: XMLHttpRequest. 400 bad Request

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, apache2

I get the following error when I try to load up a Fullcalendar page. The calendar loads but I cannot save anything on the calendar.

```
http://localhost/atmtest/frontend/web/index.php?r=atm/wpheader/jsoncalendar&wphid=10601&start=2023-01-22T00%3A00%3A00-04%3A00&end=2023-01-29T00%3A00%3A00-04%3A00
```

I am using PHP 8.2 and Apache 2.4.41 Ubuntu.

FullCalendar v5.8.0

The following code is from the main.min.js file is just one part that is throwing the error.

```
 function gi(e, t, n, r, o) {
        var i = null;
        "GET" === (e = e.toUpperCase()) ? t = function(e, t) {
            return e + (-1 === e.indexOf("?") ? "?" : "&") + mi(t)
        }(t, n) : i = mi(n);
        var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
        a.open(e, t, !0),
        "GET" !== e && a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
        a.onload = function() {
            if (a.status >= 200 && a.status < 400) {
                var e = !1
                  , t = void 0;
                try {
                    t = JSON.parse(a.responseText),
                    e = !0
                } catch (e) {}
                e ? r(t, a) : o("Failure parsing JSON", a)
            } else
                o("Request failed", a)
        }
        ,
        a.onerror = function() {
            o("Request failed", a)
        }
        ,
        a.send(i)
```

[image]

EDIT
Here is the controller code:

```
public function 
actionJsoncalendar($start=NULL,$end=NULL,$_=NULL,$wphid)
    {
        $empid = Wpheader::find()->select(['wph_empid'])->where(['wph_id' => $wphid])->one();

        $data =array();

        $times = Planner::find()->joinWith(['task','header'])->where(['pl_empid' => $empid])->all();

        $params = [':empid' => $empid['wph_empid']];

        $approvedtill  = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select wph_enddate FROM wpheader where wph_id = (SELECT max(wph_id) FROM wpheader where wph_empid = :empid and wph_status > 0)', $params)
            ->queryOne();

        //$approvedtilldate = json_encode();

        //var_dump($approvedtill['wph_enddate']);
        //echo $approvedtill['wph_enddate'];
        //die();

if(is_array($approvedtill)){
        foreach ($times AS $time){
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $time->pl_id,
                'title' => $time->pl_title,
                'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time->pl_start)),
                'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time->pl_end)),
                'color' => ($time->pl_title == 'Lunch') ? '#378006' : ($time->task->task_priority == 'Urgent' ? '#a60a0d' : ($time->task->task_priority == 'High' ? '#ad3a05' : ($time->task->task_priority == 'Medium' ? '#610861' : ($time->task->task_priority == 'Low' ? '#086118' : '#05a321')))),
                'editable' => ($time->pl_start > $approvedtill['wph_enddate']) ? true : false,
            );
          
        }
        
}
        //var_dump(json_encode($data));
        //die();
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

EDIT 2
This is the view page of the calendar.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: { 
                    left:'prev,next today',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek', 
                    center: 'title',

                },
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                selectable : true,
                //selectHelper: true,
                events : "index.php?r=atm/wpheader/jsoncalendar&wphid=<?= $model->wph_id; ?>",
                editable: true,
                eventResize: function(info) {
                    //alert(info.event.title + " end is now " + info.event.end.toISOString());
                    
                    var startTime = moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var endTime = moment(info.event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var eventID = info.event.id;
                    
                    var data = JSON.stringify({ 
                        'start': startTime,
                        'end':endTime,
                        'id':eventID,
                    });

                    
                    $.ajax({
                      url:'index.php?r=atm/planner/updatefromplanner',
                      type:"POST",
                      data:{start:startTime, end:endTime, id:eventID},
                      success:function()
                      {
                       calendar.refetchEvents();
                       alert("Plan Updated");
                      }
                    });
                    
                    
                },

                eventDrop: function(info) {
                    //alert(info.event.title + " end is now " + info.event.end.toISOString());
                    
                    var startTime = moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var endTime = moment(info.event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    var eventID = info.event.id;
                    
                    var data = JSON.stringify({ 
                         'start': startTime,
                         'end':endTime,
                         'id':eventID,
                    });
                        
                    $.ajax({
                      url:'index.php?r=atm/planner/updatefromplanner',
                      type:"POST",
                      data:{start:startTime, end:endTime, id:eventID},
                      success:function()
                      {
                       calendar.refetchEvents();
                       alert("Plan Updated");
                      }
                    });
                    
                    
                },

                eventClick: function(info) 
                {
                    var eventID = info.event.id;
                    if(info.event.title == 'Lunch'){
                        alert("This is Lunch Time");
                    }else{
                        {
                            $titletest = info.event.title;
                            if(confirm("Task -" +$titletest +". \n\nDo you want to remove it?")){
                                var eventID = info.event.id;
                                $.ajax({
                                  url:'index.php?r=atm/planner/deletefromplanner',
                                  type:"POST",
                                  data:{id:eventID},
                                  success:function()
                                  {
                                   calendar.refetchEvents();
                                   alert("Plan Deleted");
                                  }
                                })
                            }else{
                                function myCallback(data)
                                {
                                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                                    var getNum = data;
                                    window.location.href = 'index.php?r=atm/tasks/view&id='+getNum["pl_taskid"];
                                }
                                
                                $.get('index.php?r=atm/planner/gettaskid',{ eventID : eventID }, myCallback);
                            };

                        };
                    }
                    
                    

                },

            });
            calendar.render();
        });
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to debug minified code (don't) and third party code (probably not a great idea to try to debug it) which probably documents how it is supposed to interact with PHP … and the PHP you haven't shown us doesn't conform to what Fullcalendar expects.

Answer (score 2):

Please recheck your request to the API. Because the backend thinks the request you are making is invalid

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another forum:
As of PHP 8.0.0, declaring mandatory arguments after optional arguments is deprecated.

Change:

```
actionJsoncalendar($start=NULL,$end=NULL,$_=NULL,$wphid)
    {
```

To

```
actionJsoncalendar($wphid,$start=NULL,$end=NULL,$_=NULL)
    {
```